# Adding a calculated field to convert string value to date in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssms, calculated-columns

I'm trying to add a calculated field to an existing table in SSMS, which will convert a string in the format `YYYYMMDD` to a date format, but I am getting errors regarding the string field not being valid.

I require the calculated field as I have '00000000' values (i.e. NULL) in the string field so can't use this in date calculations.

The code I'm using is :

```
ALTER TABLE [TEM].[AssignmentRates] 
    ADD [Date_Expired] DATE NULL
    (SELECT CONVERT([date], CASE WHEN [Expiry_Date]='00000000' THEN NULL ELSE [Expiry_Date] END))
```

where `[Expiry_Date]` is the string column I'm trying to convert, and `[Date_Expired]` is the name of the calculated column I'm trying to add.

I get this error:

> Invalid column name 'Expiry_Date'

against both instances of that field name, and can't work out why. If I run the query as a stand alone `SELECT` it returns the required results.

Using table aliases or the full database, table and column name for it don't appear to work either.

It's probably something incredibly obvious, but I haven't been able to work out what it is.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear.  You need to reference a valid column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error on `expiry_date` seems quite clear -- that is not the name of a column in the table.  But you can simplify the logic:

```
ALTER TABLE TEM.AssignmentRates ADD Date_Expired AS
    (TRY_CONVERT(date, Expiry_Date));
```

Actually, the nested `SELECT` may have caused an issue.  That would not normally be used for a computed column.

Comment: The TRY_CONVERT worked for me in this scenario. Thanks for your help Gordon. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntax issue

```
alter table [TEM].[AssignmentRates] 
    ADD [Date_Expired]
as 
(
case Expiry_Date when '00000000' then null else cast(Expiry_Date as date) end
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax was invalid for a computed column. What you had was actually adding a regular column (successfully) but then the attempting to run a `select` statement which was causing those column-name errors as it didn't have a `from` clause for context.

```
ALTER TABLE TEM.AssignmentRates /* don't do this */
ADD Date_Expired DATE NULL /* implied end of statement */
(SELECT CONVERT(date, CASE WHEN Expiry_Date = '00000000' THEN NULL ELSE Expiry_Date END));
```

Had you used the proper syntax, you'd at least get an informative error:

```
ALTER TABLE TEM.AssignmentRates /* error! */
ADD Date_Expired AS
  (SELECT CONVERT(date, CASE WHEN Expiry_Date = '00000000' THEN NULL ELSE Expiry_Date END);

/*ERROR: Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.*/
```

But really you didn't need a subquery in the first place:

```
ALTER TABLE TEM.AssignmentRates /* success */
ADD Date_Expired AS
  CONVERT(date, CASE WHEN Expiry_Date = '00000000' THEN NULL ELSE Expiry_Date END);
```

Gordon has a point about just using `try_convert()` though.